# 3 monkeys, printing values have to be synced with semaphores

Tags: c, unix, pthreads

3 Monkeys, everyone of them prints its value. Monkey1() prints 1, and so on. The first monkey is the strongest and he prints twice 1, then monkey2 prints 2, and then again monkey1 prints, then monkey2, and then monkey3 can print his value.

**Expected output:**
`1 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 1 2` and so on..

**I am allowed to use only 2 semaphores, each monkey is a thread.**

Well, I have been thinking about it for over an hour and I am still not sure how to implement this. I would love to get some directions on how to approach this.

Here how the code looks like, if this will help of what system/language I am using, the code isn't working at the moment of curse..

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

//3 monkeys so N = 3
#define N 3

sem_t s1,s2;

void* Monkey1(void* param)
{
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      printf("1");
      sem_wait(&s1);
  }

}
void* Monkey2()
{
     int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
        sem_post(&s1);
    }
    printf("2");
    sem_wait(&s2);
}
void* Monkey3()
{
    printf("3");
    //sem_wait(&s1);
}


void main()
{
    pthread_t thread[N];
    int i, ans[N];

    sem_init(&s1, 0, 1);
    sem_init(&s2,0,0);

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        ans[i] = i + 1;
    }   

    if (pthread_create ( &thread[0] , NULL , Monkey1 , (void*)&ans[0])  != 0 )
    {
        perror( "Could not create thread" );
        exit(1);
    }


    if (pthread_create ( &thread[1] , NULL , Monkey2 , (void*)&ans[1])  != 0 )
    {
        perror( "Could not create thread" );
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pthread_create ( &thread[2] , NULL , Monkey3 , (void*)&ans[2])  != 0 )
    {
        perror( "Could not create thread" );
        exit(1);
    }


    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        pthread_join( thread[i], NULL );
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it can be implemented (I have included comments to explain how it works; not that both sempaphores are initialized with value 1 and that there are some `sleep(1)` calls to make thread interlacing visible on the screen):

```
#define N 3

sem_t s1, s2;

void *Monkey1(void *param) {
  while (1) {
    sleep(1);
    for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
      sleep(1);
      sem_wait(&s1);
      for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        printf("1\n");
      }
      sem_post(&s1);
    }
  }
}
void *Monkey2() {
  while (1) {
    sleep(1);
    sem_wait(&s2); // Wait for monkey 3
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
      sleep(1);
      sem_wait(&s1); // Wait for monkey 1
      printf("2\n");
      sem_post(&s1);
    }
    sem_post(&s2);
  }
}
void *Monkey3() {
  while (1) {
    sleep(1);
    sem_wait(&s2); // Wait for monkey 2
    sleep(1);
    sem_wait(&s1); // Wait for monkey 1
    printf("3\n");
    sem_post(&s2);
    sem_post(&s1);
  }
}
int main() {
  pthread_t thread[N];
  int i, ans[N];

  sem_init(&s1, 0, 1);
  sem_init(&s2, 0, 1);

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    ans[i] = i + 1;
  }

  if (pthread_create(&thread[0], NULL, Monkey1, NULL) != 0) {
    perror("Could not create thread");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (pthread_create(&thread[1], NULL, Monkey2, NULL) != 0) {
    perror("Could not create thread");
    exit(1);
  }

  if (pthread_create(&thread[2], NULL, Monkey3, (void *)&ans[2]) != 0) {
    perror("Could not create thread");
    exit(1);
  }

  for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    pthread_join(thread[i], NULL);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It almost works. It prints 211211231121123.. The first 2 has to be deleted. do you know how to fix that?

Comment: Also, I don't know how to follow it. :(

Comment: Monkey 2 may or may not start - it depends on in what order are the threads are joining (it could be fixed using mutex). But from there, it works exactly like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

You could change a little the Monkey1,2,3 functions like:

```
void* Monkey1(void* param)
{
  int i;
  //it starts to print first, two times number 1 and triggers Monkey 2
  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      printf("1");
  }
  sem_post(&s1);//start Monkey2
  sem_wait(&s2);
   for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      printf("1");
  }
 sem_post(&s1); //start Monkey2 and Monkey3 but Monkey3 waits also sem2
 sem_post(&s1); 
}
void* Monkey2()
{
     int i;
    sem_wait(&s1); //doesn't start until Monkey 1 allows 
    printf("2");
    sem_post(&s2);
    sem_post(&s2); //allow both Monkey1 and Monkey2 but Monkey2 needs also s1 sem
    sem_wait(&s1); //wait Monkey 1
    printf("2");
    sem_post(&s2);
}
void* Monkey3()
{
   sem_wait(&s2); 
   sem_wait(&s1); 
   sem_wait(&s2);
   printf("3");

}
```

Comment: Well, it does not work. I init the sem to 0,0 both, and it printed 112112

Comment: I edited the answer before 1 min and added one more `sem_post(&s1); ` at the end of Monkey1 did you try this version ?? , also I forgot to mention that s1,s2 are initialized in 0....

Answer (score 0):

This is a little tricky to get it right. Monkey 1 can only be waken up by monkey 2 using semaphore 1, and monkey 3 can only be waken up by monkey 2 using semaphore 2. This will guarantee the print order. To repeat, simply putting inside a while loop.

```
void* Monkey1(void* param)
{
  int i;
  //it starts to print first, two times number 1 and triggers Monkey 2
  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
      printf("1");
  }
  sem_post(&s1);//start Monkey2
  sem_wait(&s1);
  for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){
    printf("1");
  }
  sem_post(&s1);
  sem_wait(&s1); 
}

void* Monkey2()
{
  sem_wait(&s1); //doesn't start until Monkey 1 allows 
  printf("2");
  sem_post(&s1);
  sem_wait(&s1); 
  printf("2");
  sem_post(&s2);
  sem_wait(&s2);
  sem_post(&s1); 
}

void* Monkey3()
{
  sem_wait(&s2); 
  printf("3");
  sem_post(&s2);
}
```

Comment: This does not work too. Assuming sem's init values are 0,0

Comment: If it is 1,0 like in the post then it prints 22111

Comment: @Ilan Aizelman WS Did you try to run it? My output is 1121123, and both semaphore should be initialized to 0